# couldn't implement registers for assignments on this clock edge(VHDL)

Tags: vhdl, fpga, modelsim, quartus

```
``--! start state logic
start_int <= start;
ssl_edge_detect_proc: process(start_int,clk)
begin
   if rising edge(start_int) then
     start_edge_old<='1';
  else
     start_edge_old<='0';
  end if;
 start_edge<=start_edge_old;
 end process;

SslProc: process(send_state,start_int,clk,rst)
variable start variable : std_logic:='0';
BEGIN   
  if rising_edge(clk) then 
    if rst = '1' then
       start_i <= '0';
       ssl_current_state <= ssl_idle;
    else
    start_i <= '0';
    CASE ssl_current_state IS
        WHEN ssl_idle =>if start_edge= '1' and send_state=idle then 
                           ssl_current_state <= ssl_start;-- this line gives me error
                                        start_variable:='1';
                                    else
                        ssl_current_state <= ssl_idle;-- this line also
                                    end if;
        WHEN ssl_start =>
                start_i <= '1';
            IF send_state=send_modecmd THEN
                               ssl_current_state <= ssl_run;
            END IF;
        WHEN ssl_run =>`your text`
            IF send_state=idle or reset_proc ='1' THEN
                               ssl_current_state <= ssl_idle;
            END IF;
    END CASE;
    end if;
     end if;
END PROCESS sslProc;`
```

This is my code to detect edge of 'start' signal which is coming from outside. In first process, the signal "start_edge" will be updated based on the edge of start signal. But the problem is when I use that signal in second process Idle state("if start_edge= '1' and send_state=idle then ).I am getting that error when I tried to assign values "ssl_current_state <= ssl_start;".If I remove that line from my code, it will not giving any error. But even with the assignments("ssl_current_state <= ssl_start;"), ModelSim giving proper results with out any error. Quartus throwing error. Could anyone help me to sort the issue..?

If I comment those two assignments in ssl_idle state, I am not getting any errors.`

Comment: See [ask] Provide a [mcve] including a specific error and the means to reproduce the problem. Note the syntax error in the variable declaration.

Comment: Could you please mark the question as answered and/or comment on the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not aware of using synchronous and combinatorial processes properly and good VHDL practices. First of all you should read up about the basics of digital logic design using VHDL. Then, also make yourself familiar with posting reproducible, concise and clear questions on SO.

Addressing your questions, there a re multiple problems with your posted code, which mostly will become clear to you once you redo your reading about VHDL design. It is also always a good idea to create a test bench and look at the simulation wave forms to understand what is happening. Following I will explain to you, how you can detect the rising edge of the start signal.

For this we use a synchonous process, meaning that this process is clocked. Thus everything in this process is synchronous to your clock signal. The rising_edge function should only be used for a clock signal, which is one of your first mistakes. Then, in this process we are registering the incoming start signal and assign it to start_d(start delayed). By comparing start and start_d, we can determine if the start signal changed from low to high. However, note that this detection happens 1 clock cycle after the actual edge. Following you find the examplatory code for that.

```
ssl_edge_detect_proc: process(clk)
begin
  if rising edge(clk) then
    start_d<= start_int;
    if start_d = '0' and start_int = '1' then
      start_edge <= '1';
    else 
      start_edge <= '0';
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```